# Stream from file .avi - Nginx + Rtmp

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I want stream to rtmp server. I try:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i "myvideo.avi" -s 480x288 -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 30k -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec libvo_aacenc -ac 1 -b:a 4k -f flv rtmp://ip/live/test
```

And did not work...  Error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Rcf.png

how to do? Thx

Comment: Your dshow input device name is `"myvideo.avi"`? See the [FFmpeg dshow device documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow).

Comment: Thanks LordNeckbeard :)

Comment: Also see http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow